# Matplotlib does not show symbols / uni-codes correctly

Tags: matplotlib, plot, unicode, fonts, symbols

In a part of a project, I need to depict some symbols. However, a few of symbols are not showing/saving properly.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

plt.subplots(1,1, facecolor='w', dpi = 150)

plt.text(0.1, 0.9, ['This is a test', "⭘" , '◔'])
plt.text(0.1, 0.8, ['This is a test', "⭘" , '◔'], fontname = 'Arial')
plt.text(0.1, 0.7, ['This is a test', "⭘" , '◔'], fontname = 'SimHei')

plt.yticks([0,0.5,1],["⭘",'◔','⏺'])

plt.savefig('unicode_error.png')
plt.show()
```

The result is as follows, where the plot does not show some symbols:
[image: plot does not show some symbols]

I am running in Win10, I tried both back-ends: nbAgg and backend_inline.

**Two main questions:**
1. How to solve the main problem of showing "⭘" or "⏺" ?
2. How to change default font to a font that is not included in `matplotlib.font_manager` (in my case "SimHei")? Currently, I am receiving the following warning:
*C:\Users\mabag\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py:1328: UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['SimHei'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans
(prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))*

Answer (score 0):

The Font in use needs to actually provide the unicode symbol. Here you may want to use

```
plt.text(0.1, 0.9, ['This is a test', "○" , '◔'])
```

or

```
plt.text(0.1, 0.8, ['This is a test', "◯" , '◔'])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It worked for the empty circle by copying and pasting your symbol. But, I am wondering what's the general solution for different symbols? 
I tried the unicode of my circle (\u2b58'), did not work either! I have lots of symbols

Comment: Does changing the font solve the problem? If so, how may I change? I tried 
`from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
from matplotlib import rcParams; 
rcParams['font.family'] = 'SimHei
rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['Tahoma','SimHei']`
Did not solve!

Answer (score 0):

After spending many hours, I found the solution:

```
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['font.family'] = 'sans-serif'
rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['Segoe UI Symbol','simHei','Arial','sans-serif']
```

However, the most important point was to delete chached `.matplotlib` folder. Te folder is usually in `c:\users\your_username\.matplotlib` (in Windows) or `home\.matplotlib` (in Linux).